# Function does not exit when it hits to return statement

Tags: go

I have a strange problem. I was playing with Go and found some very strange behaviour that I couldn't figure it out.

When I run the `findMatchingSum` function, it searches the expected sum by if sum is bigger I decrement the last index by 1, if bigger, increment the first index by one.

However, when I debug the code, it hits first if statement and should return true, however instead it directly goes and runs last else if statement.

The confusion starts here. On the 3rd iteration it hits the if statement goes into that block but does not quit the function.

Here is the code;

```
package main

import "fmt"

var arr  = []int{1,2,4,4}

func main() {
    s := findMatchingSum(arr, 8, len(arr) - 1, 0)
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func findMatchingSum(arr []int, sum , last, first int ) bool {
    if arr[first] + arr[last] == sum {
        return true
    } else if  arr[first] + arr[last] > sum {
        findMatchingSum(arr, sum, last - 1, first)
    } else if arr[first] + arr[last] < sum {
        findMatchingSum(arr, sum, last, first + 1)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Where are you expecting it to quit the function?

Comment: Hi Flimzy, thanks to @haasc, i figured it out. I was just confused when i debug the program, it was hitting return statement and i thought function should exit on that point and return the true value. My mistake. Thank you anyway for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to "return" from the else-if branches. This should work:

```
func findMatchingSum(arr []int, sum , last, first int ) bool {
    if arr[first] + arr[last] == sum {
        return true
    } else if  arr[first] + arr[last] > sum {
        return findMatchingSum(arr, sum, last - 1, first)
    } else if arr[first] + arr[last] < sum {
        return findMatchingSum(arr, sum, last, first + 1)
    }
    return false
}
```

If you don't do this, the third branch will be executed, but the function won't exit - it will jump to the next instruction, which is "return false".

Comment: Thats kinda odd i think. I couldn't get when it hits return statement, as far as i know function should exit and return the value. But in this example it hits the return however still continues to execute. Isn't it odd ? Is it something to do with language semantics ? 

And your code works perfectly fine thank you for that :)

Comment: Let me clarify it a little better: this is something that happens with pretty much every imperative language (Java, C, C#, C++, JavaScript, Python, PHP, etc). When you call "findMatchingSum", you are not jumping inside the same function - you are actually calling a NEW function. If you don't use a "return" or a variable to store whatever value that function returns, you are throwing it away. Try researching **recursion** to make sure you understand how the call stack works.